# Is my correction of the sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar

> I think Raveena is the most talented of the two.

Actual answer is **Only one error** i.e **Most** must replaced with **More**.

But I find another error is **of the** must replaced with **than**

My Sentence:

> I think Raveena is the more talented **than** two.

Is my sentence correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second correction is not needed.

When you use a comparative or superlative, you have a few options:

> (1) **X** is **more** talented (**than** **Y**).

(1) is a direct comparison between two entities.

> (2) **X** is **the most** talented (in the group).

(2) picks out one person as more talented than everyone else in the group.

Then we have the structure that was on your assignment:

> (3a) **X** is **the more** talented (**of the two**).
>
> (3b) **X** is **the most** talented (**of the three** / **of all**).

(3) is very much like (2). It picks out one person as more talented than everyone else in the group. Here, "of the three" means something like "when considering the three (people)".

But when the group consists of *exactly* two people, you change "the most" into "the more".
This is what you see in your sentence.